# Sort spring beans and save beans directly in a collection

Tags: java, spring, comparator

I am new to Spring and java. I am trying to compare two Spring beans property values and sort according to that.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
    Circle circle = (Circle) context.getBean("circle");
    Rectangle rect = (Rectangle) context.getBean("rectangle");
    Square sq = (Square) context.getBean("square");
    System.out.println("Area of Circle: "+circle.calculateArea());
    System.out.println("Area of Rectangle: "+rect.calculateArea());
    System.out.println("Area of Square: "+sq.calculateArea());
}

}
```

Now based on the area i want to sort the spring beans/objects and save the objects in a collection based on the area. Can anyone suggest what to use here? Comparator? If so how can we use it for spring beans? Any  additional methods available in spring which will make life easy? Can anyone please suggest or provide an example please?Or similar threads ?

Comment: Spring beans are POJOs ;-)

Comment: So how can i achive this use case ? :( @SundararajGovindasamy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use polymorphism.

1. Create an interface (perhaps called `ThingsWithArea`).
2. Implement this interface in each of your shape classes.
3. Store the beans in a `Collection` (I like `List`).
4. Create a `Comparator<ThingsWithArea>` class.
    Use area as the sorting criterion therein.
5. Use comparator to sort the list.

Comment: So you mean something like this? List<ThingsWithArea> areaList = new ArrayList<ThingsWithArea>(); //add Circle and Rectagle and Square and compare them? @DwB

Comment: I prefer `List<ThingsWithArea> areaList = new LinkedList<>()`, but yes.  Once you have the list, you must create the objects and add them to the list.

Comment: this si done as suggested by you @DwB. Thanks for your time :)